# How to fix HTML page firmly, removing scroll bar to scroll down?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I would like to layout all the contents of the page in a fixed/firmly way, i.e. there is no space to scroll down the page with the scrollbar (therefore removing the possibility of scrolling down). As you can see from the image, there is a vertical scrollbar on the right side and therefore there is room to scroll down. I would like to remove it and layout everything in a fixed/firmly way.

I SPECIFY that the heights of the two navbars will change, because these in the code are only examples, so i would need to understand how to set the dimensions in case of changing the heights of the navbars
​
[image]

If I only use the 3 panel `wrapper` (without the two navbars)
, then it sets fixed and leaves no gaps at the bottom. Instead, if I add two navbars, space is created at the bottom to scroll the page with the scrollbar.

**P.S:** For the yellow center panel, i would like to continue using a custom fixed height (e.g. `.center1 {height: 300px}` or something similar)

**EDIT:** I replaced the two navbars and the image due to various problems, so I replaced their Html and Css code (shrinking them in height with .navbar {padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;}

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* NAVBAR and SUB-NAVBAR */
.navbar {
  /* --bs-navbar-padding-x: 0; */
  /* --bs-navbar-padding-y: 0.5rem; */
  /* padding: var(--bs-navbar-padding-y) var(--bs-navbar-padding-x);  */
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  }


/* 3 PANELS */

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  /* 
      --min-width in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;"> 
      */
  min-width: var(--min-width);
}

.pane:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pane:has(.pane) {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pane>.pane {
  /* 
      --min-height in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
      */
  min-height: var(--min-height);
}

.gutter {
  --l: 100%;
  --s: 10px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.gutter-v {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--l);
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter-h {
  height: var(--s);
  width: var(--l);
  cursor: row-resize;
}



.left {
  width: 600px;
}

.center_container {
  width: 650px;
}

.center1 {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.center2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #991717;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">


<header class="container-fluid p-0">


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg red">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NAVBAR</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">One</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Two</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Three</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <nav id="navbar-two" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">


    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SUB-NAVBAR</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <p class="text-danger">Lesson</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</nav>

</header>




<div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
<div class="pane left">
  This is the left pane.
</div>

<div class="pane center_container">
  <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
  <div class="pane center1">
    This is the center pane1
  </div>
  
  <div class="pane center2">
    <div class="gutter gutter-h"></div>
    This is the center pane2.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pane">
  <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
  <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have added the id in the header tag `id="main-header"`, added CSS in the `.wrapper` and `.pane` classes, and also added a script to count header height and remove that height from the wrapper.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* NAVBAR and SUB-NAVBAR */
.navbar {
  /* --bs-navbar-padding-x: 0; */
  /* --bs-navbar-padding-y: 0.5rem; */
  /* padding: var(--bs-navbar-padding-y) var(--bs-navbar-padding-x);  */
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  }


/* 3 PANELS */

.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  /* 
      --min-width in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;"> 
      */
  min-width: var(--min-width);
  overflow: auto;
}

.pane:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pane:has(.pane) {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pane>.pane {
  /* 
      --min-height in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
      */
  min-height: var(--min-height);
}

.gutter {
  --l: 100%;
  --s: 10px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.gutter-v {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--l);
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter-h {
  height: var(--s);
  width: var(--l);
  cursor: row-resize;
}



.left {
  width: 600px;
}

.center_container {
  width: 650px;
}

.center1 {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.center2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #991717;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">


<header class="container-fluid p-0" id="main-header">


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg red">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NAVBAR</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">One</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Two</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Three</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <nav id="navbar-two" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">


    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SUB-NAVBAR</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <p class="text-danger">Lesson</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</nav>

</header>




<div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
<div class="pane left">
  This is the left pane.
</div>

<div class="pane center_container">
  <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
  <div class="pane center1">
    This is the center pane1
  </div>
  
  <div class="pane center2">
    <div class="gutter gutter-h"></div>
    This is the center pane2.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pane">
  <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
  <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  function updateHeaderHeight() {
const header = document.getElementById('main-header');
const headerStyles = getComputedStyle(header);
const headerHeight = header.offsetHeight + parseFloat(headerStyles.marginTop) + parseFloat(headerStyles.marginBottom);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--header-height', headerHeight + 'px');
  }

  // Initial update
  window.addEventListener('load', updateHeaderHeight);

  // Update on scroll
  window.addEventListener('scroll', updateHeaderHeight);

  // Update on window resize
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateHeaderHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: You said "Note: Please make sure that the height of the header and menu sections will not change". I would like to change the height of the two navbars. The ones in my code were just an example. QUESTION 1: How can I change the height of the two navbars and always obtain a fixed/steady layout without a scrollbar? QUESTION 2: Can't I put everything (navbar + navbar + wrapper) in a container that adapts to the screen with fixed layout?

Comment: how did you count 130px?

Comment: I have updated the code to the latest version; please check. Firstly, I count height of the header manually, but in the latest version, you don't need to count the height manually.

Comment: Yes, it's fine now, but there's a problem. If you test the code in the full-screen snippet, you'll see that there is still some space at the bottom and the scroll bar scrolls down slightly. The vertical scroll bar scrolls very slowly, but there is some space at the bottom. How come? Can you review and edit your solution please?

Comment: Its may be possible because of loading of the logo after sometime, I have update code again please check.

Comment: Your solution is good.In the snipper there are no problems.However,if I apply your code to my project,there are problems:there is space at the bottom of the screen and therefore the scrollbar.In my project,however,i am using two different navbars than those in the question.I didn't think they made a difference to the solution.I apologize.I updated my question: i replaced the two navbars,therefore their related HTML and some of their Css. I apologize for the inconvenience.In the meantime i voted for your solution. Could you update your kind reply and help me please? Thank you

Comment: @Nodigap I have updated the code with the latest version.

Comment: PART 1 Yes. Your code works perfectly. Thank you. I was thinking of using a simpler solution without forcing the code with JS, but don't worry, I think I'll accept your answer anyway (in the absence of better answers). In the meantime I voted for you :) A curiosity: I'm doing various tests to write simpler code without js. This works, do you think the code is correct? https://jsfiddle.net/2nfktj8a/ It works correctly, but I'm not sure I wrote the css code in the best way. Could you give me your opinion (or even update your question with a version without JS for layout?)

Comment: PART 2. (continuation of comment above) Don't worry, you can take inspiration from my code in jsfiddle, because I think there is very little or no code to fix

In HTML, I created a <main>, and then deleted style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;" from <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">

In the CSS, I added height: 100% to the .wrapper. Also in the Css I added html, body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100dvh; font: 1.1rem/1.4 sans-serif;} and main { flex: 1; }. It's correct?

Answer (score 2):

- Set your HTML, BODY to height 100dvh  since that's you max app height
- Make use of flex and `flex: 1` for the elements you want to auto-size
- You could also make use of CSS grid in order to simplify the placing and nesting of your panes elements:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100dvh;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#msg {
  background: hsl(170 40% 80%);
}
#nav {
  background: hsl(170 40% 90%);
}

.panes {
  --gutterSize: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "html css js      output" auto
    "html css console output" auto
    / 1fr  1fr 1fr     2fr;
}

[data-pane] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: hsl(200 10% 20%);
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 3rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  &:has(> .gutter-v) {
    padding-left: var(--gutterSize);
  }
  &:has(> .gutter-h) {
    padding-top: var(--gutterSize);
  }
}

[data-pane="html"] {
  grid-area: html;
}

[data-pane="css"] {
  grid-area: css;
}

[data-pane="js"] {
  grid-area: js;
}

[data-pane="console"] {
  grid-area: console;
  background: #000;
}

[data-pane="output"] {
  grid-area: output;
  background: #fff;
}

.gutter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: hsl(200 10% 30%);
}

.gutter-v {
  width: var(--gutterSize);
  height: 100%;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter-h {
  height: var(--gutterSize);
  width: 100%;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<header>

  <div id="msg" class="p-1">
    <div class="container">Support us, become a sponsor! &emsp; &times;</div>
  </div>

  <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Code Monster</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HTML</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CSS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">JS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Output</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<main class="panes">
  <div data-pane="html">
    HTML
  </div>

  <div data-pane="css">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    CSS
  </div>

  <div data-pane="js">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    JS
  </div>

  <div data-pane="console">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <div class="gutter gutter-h"></div>
    $ _
  </div>

  <div data-pane="output">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <iframe id="preview" src="//example.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I respect your work so much,but i would prefer code without grid-template.I would like to use a code that corresponds to my code(or something very similar),because the various panes are resizable (by dragging mouse on the line),but I have not published the JS code so as not to waste time.If I use your grid-template,then I have trouble connecting it with the JS code to scale.I also read that grid-templates have compatibility issues with older browsers from 2017-2018,but maybe I could be wrong. However I updated my question,replacing two navbars and CSS. Could you help me please?

Comment: Part 2 (continuation to new comment above): I saw that you changed the title of my question, but it wasn't actually what I wanted: the question is not about layout like CodePen, jsFiddle, jsBin. It's a similar layout, but it's just a coincidence, because I might as well not have used it: the question concerns fixing/blocking/stopping the layout (WHATEVER IT IS and not only layout like CodePen, ecc) and removing the scrollbar. Anyway, I voted for your question. I hope you will help me with what I wrote in the previous comment. Thank you :)